# ... mankind and man's place

Tags: possessives

> For people do not and cannot think in isolation from society, and therefore from the class interests and class struggles which pervade society, any more than they can live and act in such isolation. A philosophy is a world outlook, an attempt to understand the world, **mankind and man's place** in the world. Such an outlook cannot be anything but the outlook of a class, and the philosopher functions as the thinking representative of a class.

*from Materialism and the Dialectical Method - Maurice Cornforth*

I want to ask about possessive case.
I don't know what the author mean by "mankind and man's place".
He means (mankind) and (man's place)  or (mankind and man)'s place?

Comment: It would probably be clearer with a comma after 'mankind'.

Comment: Here, "man" IS "mankind", so only "(mankind) and (man's place)" makes sense.

Comment: It's an attempt to understand (a) the world, (b) mankind, and (c) man's place in the world. (Of course, nowadays we avoid the m-word and say 'humanity'.)

Comment: I've been speaking English for years and years, and I agree that there's something distracting about constructions like this. When a business is named Kim and Arthur's, for example, I always wonder why it isn't Kim's and Arthur's. The fact that it usually isn't, and people seem to perceive the lone apostrophe-s as attached to the whole expression, makes you think twice. But in the example in your question, I agree with gotube's observation above, that the apostrophe must not run all the way back to the first noun, because then Cornforth would have said the same thing twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it referring to the world, ***mankind as a whole*** and then ***man's place in the world***, as an entity, as a person. This enumeration establishes that these three are interrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not completely clear, it seems to me he is making a list.

A more clear way to represent this would be to add an oxford comma, making the list say

"...an attempt to understand the world, mankind, and man's place in the world."

The author seems to be saying that philosophy is an attempt to understand (1) the world, (2) mankind, and (3) man's (as in your own) place in the world.